# f:convertDateTime with timeZone not working as expected

Tags: jsf, timezone

I am using JSF to show time on a page. I use it like this:

```
<f:convertDateTime pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" timeZone="Europe/Helsinki"/>
```

My question is: can I use UTC to define timezone? I have tried to use:

```
<f:convertDateTime pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" timeZone="UTC+3"/>
<f:convertDateTime pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" timeZone="EST+6"/>
<f:convertDateTime pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" timeZone="EEST"/>
```

But none of them worked.

Primefaces do not support all official timezone names, for instance Azerbaijan(UTF+4) is AST, but it will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution replacaing UTF with timezone abbreviations. I have found abbreviations on page: https://savvytime.com/

For Helsinki(UTF+2) the abbreviation is EST:

```
<f:convertDateTime pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" timeZone="EST"/>
```

For Stockholm(UTF+1) is CET:

```
<f:convertDateTime pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" timeZone="CET"/>
```

And it worked.